# Error - POST /dsahboard/api/investigator HTTP/1.1 400 160 - Django REST API error

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-rest-framework, jquery-datatables-editor

I am trying to incorporate DataTables Editor into a Django REST API. While I am able to get the datatable to display, the create button will not work and returns
`"POST /dashboard/api/investigator/ HTTP/1.1" 400 160` I've setup the editor according to the documentation but the API still won't seem to accept it. The 400 status code indicates it is a bad request, but what does the 160 mean? Can anyone provide input if I setup the datatable wrong?

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views

from rest_framework import routers
from .views import StudyList, StudyDetail, InvestigatorView

app_name = 'dashboard'
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('study', views.StudyView)
router.register('investigator', views.InvestigatorView)
router.register('lead', views.LeadView)
router.register('institution', views.InstitutionView)
router.register('site', views.SiteView)

investigator_list = InvestigatorView.as_view({
    'get': 'list',
    'post': 'create'
})
investigator_detail = InvestigatorView.as_view({
    'get': 'retrieve',
    'PUT': 'update',
    'patch': 'partial_update',
    'delete': 'destroy'
})

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.datatables, name='datatable'),
    path('investigator/', views.datatables_investigator, name='datatables_investigator'),
    path('api/', include(router.urls)),
    path('api/investigator/', investigator_list, name='InvestigatorList'),
    path('api/investigator/<int:pk>', investigator_detail, name='InvestigatorDetail'),
    path('api/study/', StudyList.as_view(), name='StudyList'),
    path('api/study/<int:pk>/', StudyDetail.as_view(), name='StudyDetail')
]
```

datatables_investigator.html

```
{% extends 'base_datatables_editor.html' %}

{% block content %}
<h1 style="text-align: center; padding-top: 1em; padding-bottom: 1em;">Investigators</h1>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <table id="InvestigatorDataTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">First Name</th>
                    <th scope="col">Last Name</th>
                    <th scope="col">Name</th>
                    <th scope="col">Email</th>
                    <th scope="col">Institution</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock content %}

{% block extra_js %}
    <script>
        var editor; 

        $(document).ready(function() {
            editor = new $.fn.dataTable.Editor( {
                ajax: {
                    create: {
                    type: "POST",
                    url:  'http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard/api/investigator/'
                    contentType: 'application/json', 
                    data: function ( d ) {
                        return JSON.stringify( d );
                    },
                    edit: {
                    type: "PUT",
                    url:  "http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard/api/investigator/_id_"
                    },
                    remove: {
                    type: "DELETE",
                    url:  "http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard/api/investigator/_id_"
                    }},
                table: '#InvestigatorDataTable',
                data: "symbol",
                defaultContent: "",
                contentType: 'application/json',
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: window.CSRF_TOKEN,
                table: '#InvestigatorDataTable',
                idSrc: "id",
                dataSrc: "data",
                fields: [ {
                    label: "ID:",
                    name: "id"
                }, {
                    label: "Last Name:",
                    name: "last_name"
                }, {
                    label: "First Name:",
                    name: "first_name"
                }, {
                    label: "Email:",
                    name: "email"
                }, {
                    label: "Institution:",
                    name: "institution",
                    ///type: "select",
                    ///placeholder: "Select an institution"
                }, {
                    label: "Created At:",
                    name: "created_at",
                    type: "datetime",
                    def:    function () { return new Date(); },
                    displayFormat: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSSS'
                    ///2022-05-19T17:59:46.167754Z
                }] 
            });
            $('#InvestigatorDataTable').DataTable({
                serverSide: true,
                ajax: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard/api/investigator/?format=datatables',
                dom: 'Bfrtrip',
                columns: [
                    {data: "last_name", },
                    {data: "first_name",},
                    {data: null, render: function ( data, type, row ) {
                        return data.first_name + " " + data.last_name
                    }},
                    {data: "email", orderable: false},
                    {data: "institution.name", name: "institution.name", orderable: true},
                    ],
                columnDefs: [
                    { targets: [2, 3, 4,], visible: true},
                    { targets: '_all', visible: false }
                ],
                select: true,
                buttons: [
                    { extend: "create", editor: editor },
                    { extend: "edit", editor: editor }, 
                    { extend: "remove", editor: editor }
                ]
            });
        });
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from dashboard.models import Study, Investigator, Lead, Institution, Site

class InstitutionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Institution
        fields = ('name', 'dept')

class InvestigatorSerializer(WritableNestedModelSerializer, serializers.ModelSerializer):
    institution = InstitutionSerializer
    class Meta:
        model = Investigator
        fields = ('__all__')
        depth = 1
        datatables_always_serialize = ('id',)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import Study, Investigator, Lead, Institution, Site
from .forms import StudyForm
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

from rest_framework import viewsets, generics
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny
from .serializers import StudySerializer, InvestigatorSerializer, LeadSerializer, InstitutionSerializer, SiteSerializer

# Datatable Views

@csrf_exempt#@csrf_protect#@ensure_csrf_cookie
def datatables(request):
    return render(request, 'datatables.html')

def datatables_investigator(request):
    return render(request, 'datatables_investigator.html')

#API Views

class InvestigatorView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Investigator.objects.all()
    serializer_class = InvestigatorSerializer
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]

class InstitutionView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Institution.objects.all()
    serializer_class = InstitutionSerializer
```

models.py

```
class Investigator(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(unique=True, primary_key=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    institution = models.ForeignKey('Institution', models.DO_NOTHING, )

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'investigator'
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.last_name)
```

Request being sent
In case the image beneath doesn't appear, here is the XHR response sent
~{"data":{"0":{"last_name":"test2","first_name":"test2","email":"test2","institution":"1"}},"action":"create"}

[Screenshot of create form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXPDu.png)

Comment: 160 means it took 160 ms to process your request and return 400 error. Plz share your model file, and also the request that you are sending for complete investigation.

Comment: I added the models file and a sample request I am sending.

Comment: The issue is in the request regarding the foregin key "institution":"1". You cannot assign value to it like this. I think if you replace it by "institution":1 it will work, since 1 is supposed to be the id number of the institution, and not a char, so remove "" around it and then try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the djangorestframework-datatables-editor python package, the URL should be set to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard/api/investigator/editor/?format=datatables` not `http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard/api/investigator/`. This what allows it to read the data within the editor format.